# How to work with OneToMany bidirectional relation

Tags: hibernate

```
i am just learning how to work with oneToMany bidirectional relation. 

i came across the following issue.
While saving the parent Entity it is getting saved and child entity too. this is creating a column in the child table with name "fk_id". but it is not saving the foreign key value into it.can you guys help me out from this?


Entity class :
        public class TestEntity implements Serializable{
             @Id 
             @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
             @Column(name = "id")
             private int id;
             @OneToMany(mappedBy="testEntity",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
             private List<TestEntityChild> testEntityChildList;
        }
        Child Class:
        @Entity
        @Table(name="testchild")
        public class TestEntityChild {
          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
          @Column(name="Test_id")
          private int testId;
          @ManyToOne
          @JoinColumn(name="fk_id")     
          private TestEntity testEntity;
        }
```

The way we are creating TestEntity. i am consuming this service from postman. where i am providing {name,roll and stream} in json format.

```
@POST
    @Path("v1/test")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //(TestEntity testEntity
    public TestEntity test(TestEntity testEntity){
        System.out.println("test to hit the service");
        System.out.println("input string :"+testEntity.getName());
        LOGGER.info("Log4j implemented in the project");
        TestEntityChild obj=new TestEntityChild();
        TestEntityChild obj1=new TestEntityChild();
        obj.setCity("delhi1");
        obj.setState("bihar1");
        obj1.setCity("delhi2");
        obj1.setState("bihar2");
        List<TestEntityChild> list=new ArrayList();
        list.add(obj);
        list.add(obj1);
        testEntity.setTestEntityChildList(list);;
        homeCareDaoImp.doaProcess(testEntity);
```

Code to save the elements in DB:

```
  session=getSession();     
    trnx=session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(testEntity);
    session.flush();
    trnx.commit();
```

Can you also let me know, why there is no must condition to implements Serializable to the entity class.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you perform the save? add the transactional method

Comment: Hi Maciej, i have added the save code in the question. Please have a look.
Thanks!

Comment: ok and how do you build testEntity? especially the setting of the List<TestEntityChild>

Comment: i have added the code. now please have a look into it.

Comment: Thanks for you effort Maciej. finally i got the cause of issue. while saving Entity, we need to assign objects to EACH side of the relationship which i was not doing. i just added the following code and now it is working fine.

obj.setTestEntity(testEntity);
obj1.setTestEntity(testEntity);

Comment: Yup that was going to be my point. Glad you worked it out by yourself

Comment: Thanks Maciej... Can you please let me know why Entity class must not to implements Serializable interface. and sometimes i also came across the situation when we must have to implement it like in case of declaring @EmbeddedId key(composite key). we are suppose to implements Serializable interface

Comment: You should always make entities seriapizable